# How to use Mocha and Unitjs to test a Sails js controller that requires login?

Tags: javascript

I am new to testing. Recently I have developed one Sails project. It works fine. But now I want to write test cases for the whole project. I am facing the problem of how to first authenticate and then test the Sails project using Mocha and Unit Js.

One of my controllers has a function that displays a report, but only to those users who are logged in. How can I write a test case for this logic?

Thanks

Comment: Try this,


      var request=require('supertest');
      var cookie;
      request(app)
      .post('/login')
      .send({ email: "user@gluck.com", password:'password' })
      .end(function(err,res){
        res.should.have.status(200);
        cookie = res.headers['set-cookie'];
        done();        
      });

      //
      // and use the cookie on the next request
      request(app)
      .get('/v1/your/path')
      .set('cookie', cookie)
      .end(function(err,res){  
        res.should.have.status(200);
        done();        
      });

I found it thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
  var request=require('supertest');
  var cookie;
  request(app)
  .post('/login')
  .send({ email: "user@gluck.com", password:'password' })
  .end(function(err,res){
    res.should.have.status(200);
    cookie = res.headers['set-cookie'];
    done();        
  });

  //
  // and use the cookie on the next request
  request(app)
  .get('/v1/your/path')
  .set('cookie', cookie)
  .end(function(err,res){  
    res.should.have.status(200);
    done();        
  });
```

thanks

Comment: This inst working, if i put the set the cookie variable and try to access it outside it shows undefined for some reason, I indeed have made it global but.

Answer (score 1):

In test enviroment you may use Cookies to persist session informations. You can check my GIST example of cookie usage wit Sails, Mocha and supertest:
[gist](https://gist.github.com/357557e48305cccfa0f14a907f3d4592.git)

Answer (score 0):

For **sails 1.0**, the following works:

First, make sure you define an own test environment where you disable `csrf`.

```
  security: {
    csrf: false
  }
```

If you do not do this, you will later not be able to authenticate in your tests and receive `403` errors.

Optionally (if you do use a ephemeral database for testing like the in-memory-db), create a user in the `lifecycle.test.js` file's callback where you find the comment `here you can load fixtures, etc.`:

```
await User.createEach([
  { id: 123123, emailAddress: 'tester@myapp.com', fullName: 'Tester 1', isSuperAdmin: true, password: await sails.helpers.passwords.hashPassword('abc123') },
]);
```

Then execute your test the following way (using promises):

```
var supertest = require('supertest');

const login = { emailAddress: 'tester@myapp.com', password: 'abc123' };

describe('This is my test', () => {

  describe('#sampleTest()', () => {
    it('should perform my action without error', () => {
      var cookie;
      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .put('/api/v1/entrance/login')
      .send(login)
      .expect(200)
      .then(response => {
        cookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];

        // Here comes what you really want to test
        return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .put('/api/v1/mycontroller/action/123')
        .set('cookie', cookie)
        .send()
        .expect(200);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This way, you first authenticate with your test user and then execute your test function with that user.

Comment: does it not matter that sails.sid is only part of the string and there are multiple parts in it?

Comment: @Vikranth sorry, I did not understand your question. Could you please explain it a bit more in detail?

Comment: No, I got it, it was a curious doubt but I figured it out. Thank you.